# How to get what is on the terminal in Nim lang

Tags: terminal, console, nim-lang

How can I store what is on the terminal (console) as a string in Nim?

For example, let's say my console is showing this:

```
   Success: Execution finished
   Success: All tests passed
(base) piero@Somebodys-MacBook-Pro Tests %
```

I want to store that as a string to a variable. 
How can I achieve that?

In bash, it may be achieved by something like this:

```
ls -ltr > ./output.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use `std/osproc`'s `execCmdEx` or `startProcess` the former runs the the command and returns the `(stdout, exitcode)` the latter allows you to interact with the process while it's running:

```
import std/[streams, osproc]
# For the startProcess variant
let myProc = startProcess("ls", args = ["-ltr"], options = {poUsePath})
discard myProc.waitForExit() # Force the program to block until done, not needed if have other computation
let myOutput = myProc.outputstream.readAll
myProc.close() # Free Resources

# For execShellEx variant
let (output, _) = execCmdEx("ls -ltr")
assert output.len == myOutput.len # Just for showcase
```